# Как сделать анимацию как в браузере "Safari" моб. версии

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу реализовать на сайте анимацию для блока header, сейчас он закреплен намертво к верхней части экрана, а хочется что бы при прокрутке вниз - он уезжал в незримую зону, и при прокрутке вверх тут же появлялся(владельцы Iphone поймут о чём идёт речь, в стандартном браузере именно такая анимация), и чтобы это не было привязано к определённому месту на странице

Comment: https://codepen.io/kaemak/pen/mHyKa/

Comment: Спасибо! Это именно то, что искал!